# Angular CLI v6: "Unknown option: '--bh'"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

**Versions**

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@angular/cdk                      6.0.1
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.15
@angular/material                 6.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

**Steps**

```
Install Angular v6 / CLI v6

ng build --configuration=stage --bh /XYZ/
```

**Error**
*Unknown option: '--bh'*

Observed behavior
The build --bh CLI option does not work in v6 (or was removed?), however the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml) hasn't been updated to reflect the new way to build with 'base-href'?

Comment: what's the error though?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try using the full option name ?

```
ng build --configuration=stage --base-href /XYZ/
```

I'm using angular 6 and this still works. However I'm not sure if it's still meant to work in the future (cf this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10447))

If the way above does not work, you can specify `baseHref` in your `configurations` section in your `angular.json` file

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {

          },
          "configurations": {
            "stage": {
              "optimization": true,
              "baseHref": "/XYZ/", //<=== here
```

Comment: ng build --configuration=stage --base-href /XYZ/

is working fine. Thanks